# Save method does not store date of birth in the database in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, datetime

I am trying to make a user registration page where I have different field types including date of birth. When I try to save the form data into the postgres database. Everything works except date of birth column saves null.

new.html

```
<%= form_for @user, :url => users_path, method: :post do |f| %>
        <input type="hidden" name="page" value="register">
          <label>First Name</label><%= f.text_field :first_name ,:class => 'textbox' %><br/><br/>
          <label>Last Name</label><%= f.text_field :last_name ,:class => 'textbox' %><br/><br/>
          <label>Email</label><%= f.text_field :email, :class => 'textbox' %><br/><br/>
          <label>Password</label><%= f.password_field(:password, :class => 'textbox') %><br/><br/>
          <label>Confirm Password</label><input type="password" name = "confirm_password" class="textbox" type="password" /><br/><br/>
          <label>Date of Birth</label><%= f.text_field :dob, :class => 'textbox' %><br/><br/>
          <label>Contact No.</label><%= f.text_field :contactno, :class => 'textbox' %><br/><br/>
        <%= f.submit('Register User') %>
      <% end %>
```

user controller

```
@user = User.create(params.require(:user).permit(:first_name, :last_name, :email, :password, :dob, :contactno))
        binding.pry
        if @user.save
          session[:user_name] = @user[:email]
          redirect_to :controller => 'dashboards', :action => 'index'
        end
```

Also, I've noticed that while looking at the console, the insert statement does not include date of birth parameter. Below is the result I see in console.

```
Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"Sm6UjUXSVSlg6KUs+UUdSXRRfd8y7f65mhyHbR9NwRnp9OJlifUgqk13yqvk4R4vq2+yIZYr2Br+a9uKTenZvg==", "page"=>"register", "user"=>{"first_name"=>"Sam", "last_name"=>"Brat", "email"=>"sm@gmail.com", "password"=>"[FILTERED]", "dob"=>"09-09-1996", "contactno"=>"1234567890"}, "confirm_password"=>"[FILTERED]", "commit"=>"Register User"}
   (0.0ms)  BEGIN
  SQL (4.0ms)  INSERT INTO "users" ("first_name", "last_name", "email", "password", "contactno", "created_at", "updated_at") VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4, $5, $6, $7) RETURNING "id"  [["first_name", "Sam"], ["last_name", "Brat"], ["email", "sm@gmail.com"], ["password", "sm12345@"], ["contactno", 1234567890], ["created_at", "2018-04-16 22:37:39.473682"], ["updated_at", "2018-04-16 22:37:39.473682"]]
   (0.0ms)  COMMIT
```

Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: **WARNING**: It's extremely important to **NEVER** store plain-text passwords. Rails comes with Bcrypt support out of the box. If you need an authentication system that does it properly by default consider using something like [Devise](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/).

Comment: `09-09-1996` is in the wrong format. It should be `YYYY-MM-DD` to validate properly.

Comment: Why would you call save after you called create? [create](https://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Base/create/class) creates an object (or multiple objects) and saves it to the database, if validations pass

Comment: @tadman Thanks for the advise. I am working on the problem however, I am stuck at an error where it says bcrypt file not found. I would have to go back and start from scratch I guess.  Also, I tried YYYY-MM-DD format and it didn't go thorugh.

Comment: You just need to include `require 'bcrypt'` in the model code that uses Bcrypt. If that's not found then you also need `gem 'bcrypt'` in your `Gemfile`.

Comment: Are you sure `dob` is the column name? The schema isn't shown here and might not match. Is that a `DATE` type column?

Comment: @MartinZinovsky Thanks You. I looked at the tutorial I am following and it does not uses create method and instead of 'create' I put 'new'.However, I am not able to store date yet.

Comment: @tadman Thanks for pointing out.! The datatype is set to time instead of datetime or date. . I really appreciate it.

Comment: @tadman Sure. I will try that. I really appreciate both of you

Comment: That'll have to be `DATE` type to accept dates. Did switching the column type help?

Comment: @tadman No success. I performed following steps. I generated a migration to update my column datatype. Restart the server. Tried using text_field and date_field inside my view. Still the same error. When I try to see what is inside the user object , it shows nil against the dob.

Comment: Can you show us your schema file?

Comment: @hashrocket   create_table "users", id: :bigint, default: -> { "nextval('tbl_user_informations_id_seq'::regclass)" }, force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "first_name", limit: 50
    t.string "last_name", limit: 50
    t.string "email", limit: 50, null: false
    t.string "password", limit: 50
    t.boolean "active"
    t.bigint "contactno"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
    **t.date "dob"**

Comment: It's usually best to include that in an edit to the question so proper code formatting can be applied.

Comment: @tadman I finally managed to figure out the issue. In my model I was converting dob into string so that I could apply model validation on it.

Comment: If you've got code that fixes this, it's worth adding a self-answer.